# How to disable annoying folder highlighting at mouseover (hovering)

Tags: desktop-icons

Concerning the Ubuntu Gnome Desktop and folder highlighting:
when I move my mouse pointer across a folder and then in an application window close to that folder - the folder stays highlighted, although I am no longer over that folder. This annoys me because it does not work right in my opinion, at times the desktop looks quite chaotic and several folders are highlighted.

[image]

Is there a way to either fix this or to completely turn off the folder highlighting by mouseover?

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome-Desktop.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this only occur when you move your mouse on to a window, from hovering over an icon on the desktop?

Comment: @galexite it also occurs if I move the mouse on the upper system bar and the dock on the left side. I think it is the general way Ubuntu behaves, I have Version 18.04 on another Computer and it behaves the same way